# Pig is not able to store JSON data after successfully reading it

Tags: json, apache-pig

Below are the commands I entered to load the JSON data, but it is not getting stored after successfully being read.

```
grunt> r11 = LOAD '/home/ginnysingh/datasets/amazon/Musical/meta_Musical_Instruments.json' USING PigStorage() AS (reviewerID:chararray, asin:chararray, reviewerName:chararray, helpful:int, reviewText:chararray, overall:int, summary:chararray, unixReviewTime:int, reviewTime:int);

grunt> f11 = FILTER r11 BY asin MATCHES '0006428320';

grunt> DUMP f11
```

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the errors I'm receiving:

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you'd probably want to use `USING PigJsonLoader()` instead of `USING PigStorage()`. In fact, you image shows that actually the LOAD failed to output anything.

Comment: the file is getting loaded successfully with the PigStorage command, bt its not storing outputs